# Automapper - how to map two different strings to object

Tags: c#, automapper

```
var stringOne = "1";
var stringTwo = "2";
```

And model:

```
public class TestModel
{
  public string TestStringOne { get; set;}
  public string TestStringTwo { get; set;}
}
```

How to to create maps and to map these two strings with Automapper?
I want to map **stringOne** to **TestStringOne** and **stringTwo** to **TestStringTwo**.

Comment: That really doesn't look like automapper can do something for you there

Comment: Please include a larger code example showing the actual thing you are trying to accomplish. If you could make up a function that did what you wanted, what would your code that used that function look like.

Comment: I have two strings aka calculations from methods that I want to map to model, what more do you need?

Comment: what do you think automapper is for?  seems like you're not understanding it's purpose.  It's a way of mapping one type to another type.    C# has a perfectly good way to assign variables to properties using the operator `=` for example   `myTestModel.TestStringOne  = stringOne` or via construction `new TestModel { TestStringOne = stringOne}`

Comment: erm, I don't want to assign like that, I want to use automapper. I guess I will have to make class and put property string and then use automapper to map, since direct string doesn't work directly.

Comment: _I don't want to assign like that, I want to use automapper_ - Automapper was designed to reduce amount of time for writing boiler plate code. In your case you spend more time for finding solution how to map, where simple idiomatic object initialization will be mot obvious approach.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to do this map as part of a larger mapping?  Because as it is, it seems you should just do:

```
var foo = new TestModel() { TestStringOne = stringOne, TestStringTwo = stringTwo };
```

If you aren't trying to do a larger mapping, then the above is better than using AutoMapper.  If you are trying to a larger mapping, then Automapper won't help you with these two, as it is meant to map one (not two or three) objects to another object.  If you really wanted to, you could lump all the objects together  into a Tuple or a new type you write for this purpose, and then configure an AutoMapper mapping for that type, but I don't gather that's what you want.